# Does the object have acceleration in the tangential direction of the path?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, projectile, free-fall

Objects thrown horizontally fall freely along the path of the parabola. Does the object have acceleration in the tangential direction of the path?  I think it is, but someone told me it was not. He also told me that there is acceleration only in the vertical direction, and the speed is constant in the horizontal direction.  Is he right?

No friction, only gravity.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming air drag (and other forms of friction) is absent then the only force acting on the object is gravity. This force causes the only, vertically downward, acceleration acting on it, that is $\vec{g}$.

---

Put slightly more mathematically, suppose the projectile is fired with an initial, horizontal velocity of $v_0$.

The velocity vector $\vec{v}$ of the projectile has two components, a horizontal one, say $\vec{v_x}$ and a vertical one, say $\vec{v_y}$. These are wholly independent of each other.

In the absence of air drag (or other forms of friction), $\vec{v_x}$ remains constant because in the absence of a net force and acc. N2L there's no acceleration in the $x$-direction.

$\vec{v_y}$ does change, due to gravitational acceleration. As a scalar:

$$v_y=-gt$$

---

As regards the tangential acceleration, consider the following vector diagram:

[image: Tangential acceleration]

$$\vec{v}=\vec{v_x}+\vec{v_y}$$

As a scalar with Pythagoras:

$$v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$$

Or:

$$v=\sqrt{v_0^2+g^2t^2}$$

$v$ is not invariant of time, so there is acceleration:

$$a=\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\Big[(v_0^2+g^2t^2)^{1/2}\Big]$$

$$a=\frac12 (v_0^2+g^2t^2)^{-1/2}(2g^2t)$$
$$a=\frac{g^2t}{\sqrt{v_0^2+g^2t^2}}$$

Comment: For sure there is no horizontal acceleration, but isn't there a component of the acceleration due to gravity in the tangential direction if by tangential we mean along the path?

Comment: No. The only acceleration (in the absence of drag) is PURELY vertical.

Comment: @Not_Einstein   I concur with Gert. In the absence of air drag there are no horizontal forces and therefor the horizontal component of velocity will be constant.

Comment: @Not_Einstein You are right, there is a gravity component in the tangential direction, so there is acceleration.

Comment: @Gert You are wrong, gravity has a gravity component in the tangent direction of the path, so there is acceleration.  There is no gravity component in the horizontal direction, so there is no acceleration.

Comment: I've deleted a number of inappropriate comments and/or responses to them.

Comment: @Gert So is the speed of the object increasing in the tangential direction of the path?

Comment: @BobD  I believe enbin is in fact correct. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I personally don't like the wording "there is acceleration in the tangential direction".  I much prefer "there is a component of acceleration in the tangential direction"; which makes it clear that the acceleration vector doesn't point the same direction as the tangent.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the object have acceleration in the tangential direction of the path?

Yes, except for in the very beginning. The acceleration is straight downwards (gravity) so for any motion that is not horizontal there is a tangential acceleration component.

> there is acceleration only in the vertical direction, and the speed is constant in the horizontal direction.

True if we assume no air drag or similar influences. Then only gravity causes an acceleration which is straight vertically downwards.

With no acceleration horizontally the horizontal speed cannot change and is constant.

Comment: When throwing an object horizontally, the parabola is obliquely downward, and gravity has a gravity component in the tangential direction of the path, so there is acceleration in the tangential direction of the path.  There is no gravity component in the horizontal direction, so there is no acceleration in the horizontal direction of the path.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero 　Gravity has a component in the tangential direction of the path, so there is acceleration in the tangential direction of the path, right?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  At any point along the trajectory the gravity force vector can be decomposed into components along and perpendicular to the velocity vector. This is consistent with the net gravity force being vertical.

Comment: @Not_Einstein So tangential acceleration exists.

Answer (score 1):

When throwing an object horizontally, the parabola is obliquely downward, and gravity has a gravity component in the tangential direction of the path, so there is acceleration in the tangential direction of the path.  There is no gravity component in the horizontal direction, so there is no acceleration in the horizontal direction.

Under conditions of gravity only.